# height of div equals to "0"

Tags: html, css

I have a very simple html code:

```
<body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="left">
                some text here
            </div>
            <div id="right">
                and some text here
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

and styles:

```
div#left {
    float: left;
    background: #e2e2e2;
}

div#right {
    float: right;
    background: #1469ab;
}
```

I want to have the height of div #container equal to heights of it's content, but now it actually 0. How to implement this behavior?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which method of 'clearfix' is best?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/211383/which-method-of-clearfix-is-best)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should apply a non-structural clearing to the container
like easyclearing http://www.positioniseverything.net/easyclearing.html

otherwise you can also specify `height: auto; overflow: hidden` to the container

Comment: overflow:hidden; is the only thing needed.

Comment: This is not always going to work in IE. You may need to add zoom:1; to be properly cross browser. Also as that is not a standard CSS rule it would be best to put it in a conditionally included CSS file.

Comment: laurencek, usually internet explorer already makes autoclearing (I don't know in IE9) but easyclearing is the best crossbrowser technique, afaik.

Comment: I hadn't actually read the easyclearing method. I was commenting more on the use of overflow clear. But I see easyclearing uses the zoom:1 anyway.

Answer (score 2):

add `overflow:auto` to your `#container`